# Powershell add to path, temporarily

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple PowerShell script to deploy a Visual Studio ASPNET Core 1 project.

Currently, in a batch file i can say

```
Path=.\node_modules\.bin;%AppData%\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
```

That will modify the path variable for the duration of the session... for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this simple thing in powershell.

Can someone help me translate this into powershell?

TIA!

Comment: Thanks Simon, this is the first hit on google when searching for "powershell add to path temporarily"!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

## Option 1: Modify the `$env:Path` Variable

1. Append to the `Path` variable in the current window:

   ```
   $env:Path += ";C:\New directory 1;C:\New directory 2"
   ```
2. Prefix the `Path` variable in the current window:

   ```
   $env:Path = "C:\New directory 1;C:\New directory 2;" + $env:Path
   ```
3. Replace the `Path` variable in the current window (use with caution!):

   ```
   $env:Path = "C:\New directory 1;C:\New directory 2"
   ```

## Option 2: Use the `editenv` Utility

I wrote a Windows command-line tool called [`editenv`](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv) that lets you interactively edit the content of an environment variable. It works from a Windows console (notably, it does *not* work from the PowerShell ISE):

```
editenv Path
```

This can be useful when you want to edit and rearrange the directories in your `Path` in a more interactive fashion, and it affects only the current window.

Comment: If you use += to add to the existing paths, make sure you add a semicolon BEFORE the added path. E.G.$Env:Path += ";C:\New directory 1;C:\New directory 2"

Comment: I reordered the information in my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: and sometimes you want the new path information first - in which case you can't use +=
ex. $Env.Path = "C:\New Directory;" + $Env.Path

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions regarding adding and prefixing - updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `$env:Path`, but if you're anxious that that isn't explicit enough, you can use [`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path',$Value,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process);
```

And GetEnvironmentVariable() can explicitly retrieve:

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process);
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User);
```